# Why does aws sts get-caller-identity (v4.0.2) show plain text credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions with AWS, Terraform and `aws sts get-caller-identity`.

A step in my workflow job is there to validate my AWS role. It looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Validate Identity with AWSrun: aws sts get-caller-identity
  run: aws sts get-caller-identity
```

The issue I am having is that instead of displaying the credentials starred out like my other pipelines like this, it actually populates the *** with real credentials, leaving my pipeline full of actual secrets for some reason.

```json
{
    "UserId": "removed_for_question:removed_for_question",
    "Account": "***",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::***:removed_for_question"
}
```

I have figured out that the reason my one pipeline is hiding the info and the other is not is because of the version I am using here:

```yaml
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.7.0
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE }}
          role-session-name: removed_for_question
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
```

vs. the one that exposes the secrets:

```yaml
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4.0.2
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE }}
          role-session-name: removed_for_question
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
```

How do I hide those credentials without having to use an old version?

Comment: GHA replaces with `***` the values it _knows_ are secrets, so e.g. the `secrets.AWS_ROLE` will be replaced wherever it appears. Actions can [register a secret](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#setting-a-secret) with GHA [like this](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/3bd0e770227859bbc3298e52dc2bf4fc0d3300ae/src/helpers.ts#L19). So if there are things you think should be secret that action _doesn't_ register, you need to raise a bug with its maintainers; SO can't really help you with that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought something like that but didn't want to be too quick in my understanding. It just boggles my mind how one version to another it hides the secrets and then the other doesn't. I can't think it good for an Arn to just be chilling in a build where anyone can check it. Thanks a ton for the reply.

Comment: Note: AWS account numbers are [not secrets](https://www.lastweekinaws.com/blog/are-aws-account-ids-sensitive-information/).